# How to stop/start the Mule flows in multiple applications using Groovy scripting

Tags: groovy, mule, mule-studio, mule-component

Is it possible to stop/start the flows which are running across in multiple applications that has been deployed with in the same mule runtime?

Looks we need to write Groovy scripting separately for each applications in order to stop/start. Can somebody help me on this to understand please?

Code snippet:-

```
  <scripting:component>
     <scripting:script engine="groovy">
        muleContext.registry.lookupFlowConstruct('targetFlow').start()
     </scripting:script>
  </scripting:component>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the description:

```
muleContext.registry.lookupFlowConstruct(<flowname>).start()
```

This is the groovy script to start the flow if the process is in stopped condition.'targetFlow' is the name of the flow that you want to start. This is a good practice to check the condition of the process that the process is stopped or started.

If you want to stop the flow you can use below code. this will stop the specified process.

```
if(muleContext.registry.lookupFlowConstruct(<flowname>).isStarted())
{
muleContext.registry.lookupFlowConstruct(<flowname>).stop();
}
else
{
flowVars.status='Process already in stopped condition';
}
```

Comment: I am able to start/start the flows without any issues, but problem is I am able to do it only with in the application i.e. my flows and groovy script should be available in the same project.

Is it possible to have Groovy scripts in 1 mule application and try to control the flows which are availalbe in mule other application?

Comment: @Sstest i do not think so. it would break the encapsulation provided by the runtime. i think you would have to provide a API (f.e. HTTP)  in one application and call it from the other application.

Comment: @Sstest Create a separate API to start and stop the mule flows running in same or different JVM Box!

Comment: @Vijay, even I am trying from separate application with in the same JVM, but still it does't work. As Yevgeniy said, MuleContext will be unique per application, its unable to access the other muleContext from the existing one.  Below I have mentioned the error stack which I am getting:-

**Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method stop() on null object**

Comment: @Sstest In that Case from a different API you need to persist a Flag to start and stop in a DB or Registry.  You can have  a DB entry like Application Name/Flag to Start or Stop. based on that you can have read the flag then you proceed with start or stop.

Comment: @Vijay, sorry, Flag will be helpful to understand the flowname and its status, but how it can resolve my requirement.  Basically I want to have 2 [1st is - application with flows and 2nd is - application with Groovy script to start/stop] application in a JVM and want to control from the latter.

Comment: @Sstest You can Design Your app like this: 

Application 1:
-----------------
Create to flow to Decide which flow shoud be started/Stopped.
May be like this Http Listener --> set properties as : flowname and action:start/stop --> make an http call to another application running in same jvm
Application 1:
-----------------
Receive Http Params flowname and flowaction --> groovy script to start/stop -->throw back a response as you need.

Comment: @Vijay, As per above suggestion, we need to write groovy script in all the applications where i am in the need to start/stop the flows.  But my question is to write only once the groovy script in a jvm and want to control  the flows which residing in the other applications.  Hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

We can start/stop the flows by writing the groovy script within the application and cannot be done across the applications since it is working on the MuleContext basis.  Below would be the easier approach.

```
 <scripting:component>
     <scripting:script engine="groovy">
        muleContext.registry.lookupFlowConstruct('targetFlow').start()
     </scripting:script>
 </scripting:component>
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done across applications, wrote a blogpost about this a while ago.

It's using the same commands but then put in an app and exposed via HTTP.

http://www.corralict.nl/how-to-start-stop-mule-flows-from-a-client-over-http/